# Using variables of template class type inside another template classes

Tags: c++, class, templates

How do I use variables of a template class inside other template classes? On compile, I receive the error `clsC is not a template` - why?

```
---- MyClasses.h: ----

template <typename T> class clsA {
public:
    void Foo(typename clsC<T> arg) {...}
    ...
};

template <typename T> class clsB {
public:
    std::vector<clsA<T>> a;
    ...
};

template <typename T> class clsC {
public:
    clsC(typename clsB<T> arg) {...}
    ...
};
```

There's been a lot of similar questions, but none which have solved my problem so far.

Comment: Forward declarations...

Comment: Ahh I didn't know you could forward declare classes (I'm coming from pure C) - Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have to add clsC forward declaration.

```
template<class T> class clsC;
```

Put this line right before clsA's definition.

Also, the following line

```
std::vector<clsA<T>> a;
```

should rewrite to

```
std::vector< clsA<T> > a;
```

because of compiler misunderstands the symbol ">>".